# Is it possible to convert a `ref bool` to a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I have a legacy scenario where a `ref bool` was being used to send a cancellation signal to an implementation. Now, I want to call a `Task`-based library method that takes a `CancellationToken` instance, which I also want to be cancelled when the boolean changes value.

This is what I have to work with:

```
void Method(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        ...
        DoThis();
        DoThat();
        ...
    }
}
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
Task MethodAsync(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        ...
        DoThis();
        await DoTheNewThingAsync(isCancelled.ToCancellationToken());
        DoThat();
        ...
    }
}
```

`ToCancellationToken()` doesn't exist in this context of course, and is used just to show the intent.

I tried to create a custom implementation of `CancellationTokenSource` but there is nothing virtual in the class that I could work with. It's also not possible to create a custom `CancellationToken` directly since it is a `struct` and cannot be inherited.

I'm aware that using a `ref bool` is a poor practice but I can't currently change the underlying implementation that relies on it, so I need a way to use it's value as the cancellation mechanism for the task-based call.

Comment: Create an extension method for booleans `public static CancellationToken(this bool isCancelled){//do stuff}`

Comment: @DetectivePikachu And how do you propose I cancel the token when the Boolean changes?

Comment: As there's no way to be informed when a `bool` changes value, whatever you come up with would need to intermittently poll the value to actually trip a `CancellationToken`. This is not going to be efficient. `CancellationTokenSource` is more than just a simple yes/no flag for cancellation, so even if there was some black magic voodoo way to alias the bool somehow, you still couldn't use that as a full-fledged implementation.

Comment: You'd have to pull all kinds of hacky tricks to make this work, event emitter with a background thread or something like that. I think you're better off either updating the legacy app to use CancellationTokens throughout, or more likely just sticking with their current scheme

Answer (score 6):

It's complicated. For a few reasons:

1. You cannot pass a parameter by `ref` to an `async` method. You're using `await`, but to use `await`, your method needs to be marked `async`. And `async` methods cannot have `ref` parameters. For example, this will not compile:

```
async Task MethodAsync(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        DoThis();
        await DoTheNewThingAsync(isCancelled.ToCancellationToken());
        DoThat();
    }
}
```

That will give you the compiler error:

> CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref, in or out parameters

2. You cannot use `ref` parameters in anonymous methods. I thought about using a `Timer` to check the variable. Something like this:

```
public static CancellationToken ToCancellationToken(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    {
        AutoReset = true,
        Interval = 100
    };
    timer.Elapsed += (source, e) =>
    {
        if (isCancelled)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    };
    timer.Enabled = true;

    return tokenSource.Token;
}
```

But that gives you the compiler error:

> CS1628: Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'isCancelled' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function

I don't see any other way to get the `bool` into the event handler by reference.

3. The closest I could get is something like this:

```
void Method(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        DoThis();
        using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
            var mytask = DoTheNewThingAsync(tokenSource.Token);
            while (true)
            {
                //wait for either the task to finish, or 100ms
                if (Task.WaitAny(mytask, Task.Delay(100)) == 0)
                {
                    break; //mytask finished
                }
                if (isCancelled) tokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            // This will throw an exception if an exception happened in
            // DoTheNewThingAsync. Otherwise we'd never know if it
            // completed successfully or not.
            mytask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        DoThat();
    }
}
```

However, that blocks the caller, so I don't entirely see how that could even be useful (how can the caller change `isCancelled` if it's blocked?). But that's kind of what your existing method is doing, so maybe it would work?

But this is super hacky. If you can at all control how anything is done upstream, do that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've hacked up a somewhat working solution:

```
public static class TaskRefBoolCancellable
{
    public static T SynchronousAwait<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> taskToRun, ref bool isCancelled)
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var runningTask = taskToRun(cts.Token);

            while (!runningTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (isCancelled)
                    cts.Cancel();

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            return runningTask.Result;
        }
    }
}

void Method(ref bool isCancelled)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        ...
        DoThis();
        var result = TaskRefBoolCancellable.SynchronousAwait(DoTheNewThingAsync, ref isCancelled);
        DoThat();
        ...
    }
}
```

**WARNING**: This code runs synchronously on calling thread. So there are no guarantees it will work nicely with other parts of the code, as it blocks the calling thread. Also, it polls the `isCancelled` variable, making it both ineffective and the cancellation is not immediate.

I would consider this a stop-gap solution as you replace the `ref bool isCancelled` with proper task-based cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a method `async Task` and still want to use `bool` semantics, you have to pass an object so that in can keep the reference to the `bool` value. This can be done without any blocking operations if `bool` parameter can be converted to `Ref<bool>` in client code:

```
public class Ref
{
    public static Ref<T> Create<T>(T value) => new Ref<T>(value);
}

public class Ref<T> : Ref
{
    private T value;

    public Ref(T value) => Value = value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => value;
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => Value?.ToString() ?? "";
    public static implicit operator T(Ref<T> r) => r.Value;
    public event Action<T> OnChanged;
}

public static class RefExtensions
{
    public static CancellationToken ToCancellationToken(this Ref<bool> cancelled)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancelled.OnChanged += value => { if (value) cts.Cancel(); };
        return cts.Token;
    }
}

public async Task Method(Ref<bool> isCancelled)
{
    var cancellationToken = isCancelled.ToCancellationToken();

    while(!isCancelled)
    {
        ...
        DoThis();
        await DoTheNewThingAsync(cancellationToken);
        DoThat();
        ...
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Fact()
    {
        var cancelled = Ref.Create(false);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            cancelled.Value = true;
        });

        var task = Method(cancelled);
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        task.Status.Should().Be(TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you need to implement a `Ref<bool>.ToCancellationToken` method. This is what the OP wants!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The question was raised in a context where it would not be possible to modify the incoming `ref bool` into a container object. If that was possible, I could simply use `CancellationToken` directly as the replacement (no need to use `Ref<bool>` for example).

Comment: @julealgon but you changed the signature of the method `Task MethodAsync(ref bool isCancelled)`. If you must keep the signature (means blocking) then you have to follow an approach similar to what @GabrielLuci suggested.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov sorry, you are correct. My example was misleading and does not reflect my actual situation. I'm not getting the bool from a parameter, but from a base class `protected` field. This means I'm free to change the signature on the call site, but I can't change the base class and its underlying cancellation mechanism in this instance.

Comment: @julealgon then it makes a solution way easier. It means you don't have to have `ref` paramter, right? And can access protected field of a base class? If that's the case my initial version of the answer does just that. If you update the question with more details of you base class and the method I will be able to provide you with some better solution. You also have to decide whether the execution of the method has to be sync or async from the perspecive of the caller (the base class). I suppose it's the base class that calls your method, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempted improvement on Euphoric's inventive [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661986/11178549). Instead of `Thread.Sleep`, this one uses the [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) overload that accepts a timeout. This way no extra delay will be imposed to the completion of the task.

```
public static void Wait(Func<CancellationToken, Task> taskFactory,
    ref bool cancel, int pollInterval = 100)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        if (cancel) cts.Cancel();
        var task = taskFactory(cts.Token);
        while (!cancel)
        {
            if (task.Wait(pollInterval)) return;
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
Wait(DoTheNewThingAsync, ref isCancelled);
```